# How to use re.findall to get only strings with lowercase letters in python

Tags: python, regex, list

Suppose if my list has `["Apple","ball","caT","dog"]`
then it should give me result `'ball` and `'dog'`.

How do I do that using `re.findall()`?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `re.findall()` here, at all.

Use:

```
[s for s in inputlist if s.islower()]
```

The [`str.islower()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) returns `True` if all letters in the string are lower-cased.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = ["Apple","ball","caT","dog"]
>>> [s for s in inputlist if s.islower()]
['ball', 'dog']
```

Use `re.findall()` to find lowercased text in a *larger* string, not in a list:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', 'The quick Brown Fox jumped!')
['quick', 'jumped']
```

Answer (score 3):

`re.findall` is not what you want here.  It was designed to work with a single string, not a list of them.

Instead, you can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.islower`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower):

```
>>> lst = ["Apple", "ball", "caT", "dog"]
>>> # list(filter(str.islower, lst))  if you are on Python 3.x.
>>> filter(str.islower, lst)
['ball', 'dog']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask how to kill a mosquito with a cannon, I guess you can technically do that...

```
c = re.compile(r'[a-z]')

[x for x in li if len(re.findall(c,x)) == len(x)]
Out[29]: ['ball', 'dog']
```

(don't use regex for this)